# how to convert array byte to org.w3c.dom.Document

Tags: java, xml, arrays

I have a Document (org.w3c.dom.Document), I convert this document to array of byte:

```
private byte[] obtenerBytesDeDocument(Document documentoXml) throws Exception {
    Source source = new DOMSource( documentoXml );
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Result result = new StreamResult(out);
    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();
    transformer.transform(source, result);
    byte[] butesXml =  out.toByteArray();
    return butesXml;
}
```

I need convert the array of byte to document newly:

```
private Document obtenerDocumentDeByte(byte[] documentoXml) throws Exception {
        ...
}
```

Any idea?

Thansks!!!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The following should work.

```
private Document obtenerDocumentDeByte(byte[] documentoXml) throws Exception {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    return builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(documentoXml));
}
```