# Convert MbElement to W3C Node in WebSphere Message Broker 7.0.0

Tags: messagebroker

I am trying to convert a **com.ibm.broker.plugin.MbElement** into an **org.w3c.dom.Node**. The environment is WebSphere Message Broker 7.0.0.

I know that version **IIB 9.0.0** has methods like **getDOMNode()** which returns a **org.w3c.dom.Node**. I cannot upgrade my environment for various reasons , Any pointers suggestions for doing this in 7.0.0.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You should not parse your message in the message flow, so leaving it in BLOB.
Then in your Java Compute you could access the message as a byte array and parse it in Java to get a org.w3c.dom.Document, like this:

[how to convert array byte to org.w3c.dom.Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21165871/how-to-convert-array-byte-to-org-w3c-dom-document)

Answer (score 0):

It's not that trivial a task as to generate the correct children of each node in the DOM tree you will need basically recreate the tree navigating the message tree as you go.

The JAXB implementation in IIB 9 is pretty much exactly what you need. Given that WMB v7 is out of support in Sept I think your best bet is taking the plunge to IIB 9 /10.

Parsing a BLOB in a JCN will work but is a pretty inefficient implementation as other nodes in your message trees wont benefit from your JCN having parsed the tree and will therefore need to reparse.