# xml-formatted stream output GEPHI-TOOLKIT

Tags: java, xml, graph, gephi

I'm writing java function using gephi-toolkit, that should produce gefx-formatted graph data, as a output stream, not a file, for further use.

If I use CharArrayWriter, or StringWriter - all xml tags being formatted as special symbols, an my output looks like this:

```
&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt;
&lt;gexf xmlns="http://www.gexf.net/1.2draft" version="1.2" xmlns:viz="http://www.gexf.net/1.2draft/viz" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.gexf.net/1.2draft http://www.gexf.net/1.2draft/gexf.xsd"&gt;
  &lt;meta lastmodifieddate="2016-03-24"&gt;
    &lt;creator&gt;Gephi 0.8.1&lt;/creator&gt;
    &lt;description&gt;&lt;/description&gt;
  &lt;/meta&gt;
  &lt;graph defaultedgetype="directed" mode="static"&gt;
    &lt;nodes&gt;
      &lt;node id="1" label="n0"&gt;
        &lt;attvalues&gt;&lt;/attvalues&gt;
        &lt;viz:size value="10.0"&gt;&lt;/viz:size&gt;
        &lt;viz:position x="-206.8857" y="-18.469671" z="0.0"&gt;&lt;/viz:position&gt;
        &lt;viz:color r="153" g="153" b="153"&gt;&lt;/viz:color&gt;
      &lt;/node&gt;
      &lt;node id="2" label="n1"&gt;
        &lt;attvalues&gt;&lt;/attvalues&gt;
        &lt;viz:size value="10.0"&gt;&lt;/viz:size&gt;
        &lt;viz:position x="-29.136229" y="80.29351" z="0.0"&gt;&lt;/viz:position&gt;
        &lt;viz:color r="153" g="153" b="153"&gt;&lt;/viz:color&gt;
```

What should I use to get xml-streamed data at the output?

Current code:

```
//Export 
ExportController ec = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(ExportController.class); 

ExporterGEXF exp = (ExporterGEXF) ec.getExporter("gexf");  
CharArrayWriter writer = new CharArrayWriter(); 

ec.exportWriter(writer, exp); 
return writer;
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer were helpful:
[how to convert array byte to org.w3c.dom.Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21165871/how-to-convert-array-byte-to-org-w3c-dom-document)

Thanks to [harun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1987208/harun)!

Working code is:

```
 StringWriter strwriter = new StringWriter();



        ec.exportWriter(strwriter, (CharacterExporter)exp);

        String str = strwriter.getBuffer().toString();



        byte[] arr = str.getBytes("UTF-8");

          DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    return builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(arr));
```